# User roles and authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, repository-pattern, login-control, user-roles

So I want to create a login page where when you enter your login credentials as a admin you get acces. If you are not a admin you get redirected back to the login page. In my database I have a field of boolean type:

```
isAdmin <--datatype(byte")
```

So how can you the best way do this?! I would like to do this in the repository pattern way as it gets easier to unit test it then.

I have googled this a lot and starting to get a bit confused on the matter. How many classes, models etc should I have?! I'm guessing one controller would do. Anyone got any good ideas?! I've read some on the DCI pattern about user roles but as it basically "only" to check that boolean in the database maybe it is overkill? Thankful for all feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I had a similar issue. It seems from your question that you are not using the default membership provider (at least as is). I didn't either. So what I did was create a new authorization attribute. In your case it could look something like this:

```
public class AdminOnlyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
    IUserRepository _UserRepository;

    public SimpleUser SimpleUser { get; set; }

    public AdminOnlyAttribute() {
        _UserRepository = new SqlUserRepository(new DbContext());
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        bool baseAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!baseAuthorized) {
            return false;
        } 

        //Here you use your repository to check if a user is an admin or not
        bool isAdmin = _UserRepository.IsAdmin(int.Parse(httpContext.User.Identity.Name));

        if (!isAdmin) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The repository method IsAdmin could be as simple as a query to check the boolean corresponding to the supplied user's ID. Something like this (please double check if `SingleOrDefault()` is necessary or not):

```
public bool IsAdmin(int userID) {
    bool isAdmin = (from user in db.Users
                    where user.ID == userID
                    select user.isAdmin).SingleOrDefault();
    return isAdmin;
}
```

And then use this in the action you want like so:

```
[AdminOnly]
public ActionResult Index(){
    //Code here...
}
```

When this returns false, your ActionResult will be an HttpUnauthorizedResult which in theory should redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful feedback. Although I'm not sure I'm clear on how the repository method IsAdmin should look? Also I'm getting a  method must have a return type on:public AuthorizeAttribute() 

Comment: @Tim The error you're getting is because I made a mistake on the constructor. See it said AuthorizeRAttribute and the class is called AdminOnlyAttribute. Change it to AdminOnlyAttribute and it should work. As to the method, I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So then in the ActionResult I should do a conditional on if user is admin?

Comment: In the Web.config, there's a section that deals with the page that should be shown after an HttpUnauthorizedResult is returned. That should be "automatic". By default it is <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" protection="All" timeout="30" /> Look for it.

Comment: Ok. So then in the end it should look like this: <forms loginUrl="~/Login" protection="All" timeout="30" /> ? Thanks!

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error on my return type on the IsAdmin method. It says that method must have a return type although I implemented it like you said. Also I'm wondering ifI am missing a namespace as it wants to implement new classes for this line: new SqlUserRepository(new DbContext()); What am I missing here?

Comment: My mistake with the IsAdmin method, The IsAdmin method should return a boolean but I forgot to specify it. Are you new to the framework and/or language? These IDE error notices are fairly self-explanatory tbh. The SqlUserRepository is a placeholder you have to replace with your own user repository class. It usually takes a DataContext class. This is pretty basic, though, so I fear the answer may be too advanced atm. I suggest you check a tutorial (like this one http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: This also assumes you're using your own user account implementation instead of the one (membership and role system) included in ASP.NET MVC. But seeing your experience with the framework, I am not quite sure this is the case, so after all... this solution may not apply to your case.

Comment: IsAdmin alternative: public static bool IsAdmin() { return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"); }

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom Membership Provider and check the user isAdmin as part of ValidateUser.

Alternatively if other users are allowed in, use a custom role provider.

The following link is a good place to start

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Is your isAdmin column a bit or a byte? It should probably be a bit. You could just create a query that checks the credentials and the IsAdmin column. If a row is returned then the login was successful.

Comment: Yes I meant that it is a bit:)

Comment: ok so you mean something like this then if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userResults = from u in db.Users
                                  where u.UserName == "admin"
                                  && u.Password == "password"
                                  select u;
            }

Comment: No, I mean more like something Kensai has written in the post above in the IsAdmin repository method except you can pass username and password. `public User IsAdmin(string username, string password) { return (from user in db.Users where user.username == username && user.password == password && user.IsAdmin == true select user).SingleOrDefault(); } `

Comment: Ah ok thanks. So to acces the result of the query in my Action I dont pass in the model as a parameter but use it like this [AdminOnly] ??