# Admin login user controller

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, admin, login-control

I'm trying to implement a simple login for admin in a MVC3 project. I'm new to ASP.NET and to MVC3. I have googled and asked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589326/user-roles-and-authorization)! have seen a lot of really nice ways of implementing this but they were all on a very abstract level and quite frankly maybe a bit to high for me at the time being. I have the credentials in my db so basically I just want to query that one and redirect the user if login matches those and if not show login form again. So this is what I got. My model:

```
  public class FormModel
{
    public bool isAdmin { get; set; }


 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Username")]
 //[Remote("ValidateUserName", "Login", ErrorMessage = "UserName already taken!")]
 [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
 [Display(Name = "Username:")]
 [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed")] 
 public string UserName { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Password")]
 [DataType(DataType.Password)]
 [Display(Name = "Password:")]
 public string Password { get; set; }

}
 public User IsAdmin(string username, string password) 
   { 
      return (from user in db.Users 
      where user.username == username && user.password == password <--- alternative here is to just match username and pass against the data I have in my db columns(testdata 'admin', 'password')
      && user.IsAdmin == true  
      select user).SingleOrDefault(); 
    }
```

And in my controller basically this right now:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //some code here maybe a conditional
        return View();
    }
```

And finally my view:

```
     @model Web.VoucherCannon.Models.FormModel
     @using (Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "myForm"})) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div> 
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <button class="button">Log In</button> 
      }
```

So now. How do I use the returned result of the query in my controller so that I can login? I'm sure I will refactor this later on and make it with a dbcontext layer and so on, but just for now I will be happy to make this work. Grateful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 2 controller actions: one for rendering the login (accessible on GET) form and one for handling the submission (accessible on POST) and performing the actual authentication.

```
// This will render the Login view (the one you have shown)
public ActionResult Login()
{
    var model = new FormModel();
    return View(model);
}

// This one is responsible for handling the submission and credential verification
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(FormModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // The user submit the form but validation 
        // (as defined on the model using DataAnnotation attributes) failed
        // => redisplay the view so that the user can fix his errors
        return View(model);
    }

    // notice that you don't need to pass parameters to the IsAdmin method
    // as it already contains the username and password as properties
    if (!model.IsAdmin()) 
    {
        // The IsAdmin method didn't verify the credentials => add a model error
        // and redisplay the login view
        ModelState.AddModelError("username", "dude you are not an admin");
        return View(model);
    }

    // OK, at this stage everything is fine => we can grant access
    // by issuing an authentication cookie
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

    // finally we redirect to some home page for admins
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
}
```

Comment: thanks that looks very nice and I totally understand the logic. Will as soon as i have tried it give you feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, I did slight modifications to my initial answer => in the case of IsAdmin method failing we should obviously redisplay the Login form instead of granting access (FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie) and redirecting.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that sounds more wise to redisplay that:). What did you make of my model?! Do you think that it is good practice to put the query at the same place as the remote validation?

Comment: It is not working. It says 'no overload for method IsAdmin, takes 0 arguments. Can't I pass in username and password as parameters in the IsAdmin method in my model?? Am I thinking wrong here??

Comment: @Tim, yes you can pass them as arguments of course. But why would you as you already have them in the model which is where this IsAdmin action is located? Simply remove them from it and inside access them like this: `where user.username == this.UserName && user.password == this.Password`. If you want you can keep them as parameters and pass them when calling the method, like this `if (!model.IsAdmin(model.UserName, model.Password))`.

Comment: ok. But it if I dont pass the two arguments as parameters in the controller it says " no overload etc" and suggests me to implement a method stub in my model aka a internal bool which throws new notImplemented. Or if I do pass them in it says that I cant use the '!' operator to operand of type models.user. Sorry for long thread but not sure what to do.

Comment: @Tim, I would suggest you start learning C# before going any further with ASP.NET MVC. That's really some basic C# stuff questions here. Your IsAdmin user returns a User object. So modify it in order to return a boolean. Here's how your IsAdmin method might look like: `public bool IsAdmin() { ... }`.